# Java JPA - save() an object with @JoinTable attribute

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to insert an row into my database. I have following sql setup (its just an example):
Table `person`:
(id, name)

Table `person_street`:
(person_id, street_id)

Table `street`
(id, name)

This should be a many to many relation. This example doesn't make sense, but I think you'll understand the idea.

Now I have these entities in java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_street",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "street_id")
    )
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Street> streets;

}
```

This is a good solution to work with my person objects (after reading them from my database).
But I have problems while inserting/creating person objects.

I want to create a new person in my frontend. It calls an REST interface at my backends side with `String name, List<Long> streets`.

Now I want to insert this new person (with the given name and streets) into my database.

But I don't want to do a select for all `List<Long> streets` on my `street` table. There is no need to change any value of the street objects. I just want to insert the link between the new person and the existing streets (in the table `person_street`).

What is the easiest way to do that?
Can I use my Person class for this, or does I need a new different class.

T

Comment: There are a many ways to do it, but what would you consider the _easiest_ one? The least time consuming? The most understandable? The shorter one? I wouldn't discard the most simple (selecting from `street`) since JPA is fast enough

Answer (score 0):

you can add this method to the Person class

```
 public void addStreets(Street street) {
        if(streets==null) {
            streets=new ArrayList<Street>();
        }
        streets.add(street);
    }
```

and after that, you get the street by the id from the street table and added to the corresponding person which you are getting from the front end after that you save the whole person.

Comment: Sure this works, but I need to access the streets table before to get the street object.  This isn't cool, because there is no need to do a select on the street table.

Comment: what data you want from the street table? can you please explain what is your requirement then it will be easy to describe?

Comment: I want no information from the street table. 
I want to save an row in the table person and I want to add the connection between a person and an already existing street object, which id I have.